# Convert matlab serial timestamp to java.util.Date

Tags: java, excel, matlab, date

I have a matlab serial timestamp  `735628.631944` and need to be converted it to java.util.Date `29.01.2014 15:10:00`.

it is very easy to convert in excel

```
string timestamp = serialTimestamp - 693960
```

select the timestamp in Excel can convert it to custom format (TT.MM.JJJ hh:mm:ss)

but how does it work internally? is there any formula for converting it in java ?

I get matlab serial timestamp from a CSV file and I am parsing it in Java. I require Java code for this conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab time is a number of days since 1/0/0000, but java.util.Date constructor expecs number of milliseconds since  1/1/1970, therefore

```
double timestamp = 735628.631944;
Date d = new Date((long)( (timestamp - 719529) * 86400000 ));
```

Here 719529 is a matlab timestamp for 1/1/1970 and 86400000 number of milliseconds in one day.

Comment: I want Java code. I get this matlab serial timestamp from a CSV file

Comment: MATLAB time is number of days from `January 0, 0000`, not `January 1, 0000`